# Why connectivity manager doesn't work on pre-lollipop devices?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I make one function in the helper class.

```
public class helpers {

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //================== method for checking internet connection  ===========
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static  boolean isOnline(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And Using this method in other classes need to make internet connection before sending json request with volley.
Now my problem is why this function work in a lollipop devices and doesn't work in pre-lollipop devices.

for e.g see this code:

```
private void sendJsonReq() {

        if (helpers.isOnline(DarsActivity.this)) {
            //creating volley object request
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, darsUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {
                       //doing network stuff
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(DarsActivity.this, "خطا در دریافت اطلاعات ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

            // LOAD MORE FUNCTION =====================================================================

            recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener(gridLayoutManager) {
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                    if (!after_url.equals("null")) {
                        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, after_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                               //doing network stuff
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                                prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                txtErrorMessage.setText("دریافت اطلاعات با مشکل مواجه شد دوباره امتحان کنید !");
                                btnErrorRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        if (helpers.isOnline(DarsActivity.this)) {
                                            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            sendJsonReq();
                                        } else {
                                            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            prgLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                            txtErrorMessage.setText("شما به اینترنت متصل نیستید . دوباره امتحان کنید !");
                                            btnErrorRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                                    if (helpers.isOnline(DarsActivity.this)) {
                                                        errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                        sendJsonReq();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        });
                        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);

                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            errorLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btnErrorRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (helpers.isOnline(DarsActivity.this)) {
                        errorLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        prgLoading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        sendJsonReq();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

When I run this code on lollipop devices error handling work perfect but when I run this on pre-lollipop devices it skip the `isOnline` method and send the json request.

Edit:

After tracing the code, I get isOnline Method in pre-lollipop devices return `true`. but why?!

Comment: what does you mean by skipping the isOnline method? maybe it returns always true?

Comment: You're right , i check it with debugger . when i get value of isOnline in my lolipop(geny motion device ) it return true value when i have connection and return false when i havn't connection , but in my android 4 geny motion device it always return true, But why ???!!!

Answer (score 0):

try this it works well :

```
 public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: use getActiveNetworkInfo(); instead of getAllNetworkInfo();

Comment: it does'nt work . i debug it and other snippet code . isOnline always return true in prelolipop devices .

Answer (score 0):

Use below code its working in all devices.

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {
        NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {

            if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI || info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE || info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: it does'nt work . i debug it and other snippet code . isOnline always return true in prelolipop devices .